# Monaco web editor isn't working after uncommenting part of the code in the method that isn't used

Tags: typescript, npm-install, antlr4, monaco-editor, npm-start

I try to add the suggestions on the Monaco web editor and have a very strange problem. Consider the class:

```
import { ExpressionContext } from "../ANTLR/ExpressionsParserGrammarParser";

import * as monaco from "monaco-editor-core";
import { ILanguageError } from "../todo-lang/ILanguageError";
import { calcFormatted } from "../todo-lang/FormatterVisitor";
import { parseAndGetASTRoot, parseAndGetSyntaxErrors } from "../todo-lang/parser";


export default class TodoLangLanguageService {
    validate(code: string): ILanguageError[] {
        const syntaxErrors: ILanguageError[] = parseAndGetSyntaxErrors(code);
        const ast: ExpressionContext = parseAndGetASTRoot(code);
        return syntaxErrors;//.concat(checkSemanticRules(ast));
    }
    format(code: string): string {
        return calcFormatted(code).value
    }

    autoSuggest(code: string, line: number, charPosInLine: number): monaco.languages.CompletionList {

        const syntaxErrors: ILanguageError[] = parseAndGetSyntaxErrors(code);
        let completeonItems: Array<monaco.languages.CompletionItem> = syntaxErrors.filter(err => err.startLineNumber == line && err.startColumn == charPosInLine).map(e => {
            let ci: monaco.languages.CompletionItem = {

                label: e.message,
                /**
                 * The kind of this completion item. Based on the kind
                 * an icon is chosen by the editor.
                 */
                kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Field,

                insertText: e.message,
                range: {
                    /**
                     * Line number on which the range starts (starts at 1).
                    */
                    startLineNumber: e.startLineNumber,
                    /**
                     * Column on which the range starts in line `startLineNumber` (starts at 1).
                     */
                    startColumn: e.startColumn,
                    /**
                     * Line number on which the range ends.
                     */
                    endLineNumber: e.endLineNumber,
                    /**
                     * Column on which the range ends in line `endLineNumber`.
                     */
                    endColumn: e.endColumn
                }
            }
            return ci;
        })

        let ci:monaco.languages.CompletionList={
            suggestions:completeonItems
        }
        return ci;
    }
}
```

Method "autosuggest" isn't used in the source code (I have commented it). Problem is Monaco Web Editor doesn't process the language functionality - syntax coloring, formatting and error highlighting.

But if I change the autosuggest method as below everything works correctly, of course without suggestions:

```
 autoSuggest(code: string, line: number, charPosInLine: number): monaco.languages.CompletionList {

        const syntaxErrors: ILanguageError[] = parseAndGetSyntaxErrors(code);
        
        let ci:monaco.languages.CompletionList={
            suggestions:[]
        }
        

    return ci;
}
```

My package.json is following:

```
{
  "name": "todolangeditor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TodoLang editor",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --open",
   "antlr4ts": "antlr4ts ./ExpressionsParserGrammar.g4 -visitor -o ./src/ANTLR"
  },
  "author": "Open",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "antlr4ts": "^0.5.0-alpha.3",
    "monaco-editor-core": "^0.18.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "antlr4ts-cli": "^0.5.0-alpha.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

When I run npm install I have the following log, there are several warnings but no error:

> npm WARN deprecated set-value@2.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1,
> please upgrade to the latest version. npm WARN deprecated
> set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the
> latest version. npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see
> https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated npm WARN deprecated
> chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since
> 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security
> updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1:
> https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated npm WARN deprecated
> source-map-url@0.4.0: See
> https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated npm WARN
> deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported npm
> WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered
> Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead. npm WARN
> deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older
> versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is
> known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for
> details. npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.2: See
> https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
>
> added 726 packages, and audited 727 packages in 4s
>
> 63 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> 17 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 8 high, 8 critical)
>
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:   npm audit fix
>
> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:   npm audit
> fix --force
>
> Run `npm audit` for details.

How to fix this problem?